# Linearization of a logarithmic function

Tags: calculus, linearization

I've following function which should be linearized:

$$f(x,y)=0.25\left(\ln\left(\dfrac{0.1x+100}{\sqrt{ y+20}}\right)\right)$$

After applying some basic rules, I got this function:

$$0.25\ln(0.1x+100)-0.125\ln(y+20)$$

How do I get rid of the natural logarithm in this function to linearize it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you say linearize, I would gess you should write down the Taylor Expansion of $\ln$ and drop everything after the first order term

Comment: at which values do you want to linearize?

Comment: Taylor is a good idea! Thanks :)